# Finding $x$ such that $(1+x^a+x^b)^2 = 3(1+x^{2a}+x^{2b})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

> Find all values of $x < 0$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$(1+x^a+x^b)^2 = 3(1+x^{2a}+x^{2b}).$$

Subtracting the left-hand side from the right-hand side and simplifying gives \begin{align*}3(1+x^{2a}+x^{2b})-(1+x^a+x^b)^2 &= 3(1+x^{2a}+x^{2b})-(1+2x^a+2x^b+x^{2a}+x^{2b}+2x^{a+b})\\&=2(-x^{a+b}+x^{2a}+x^{2b}-x^a-x^b+1) .\end{align*} This equals zero and thus $-x^{a+b}+x^{2a}+x^{2b}-x^a-x^b+1 = 0$. How can we continue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cauchy-Schwarz inequality says
$$(1+x^a+x^b)^2\le (1+1+1)(1+x^{2a}+x^{2b})$$
and equality happens when
$$1=x^a=x^b.$$

Or to continue your argument (actually a proof of C-S inequality in this case):
$$2(-x^{a+b}+x^{2a}+x^{2b}-x^a-x^b+1) = (x^a-x^b)^2+(x^a-1)^2+(x^b-1)^2.$$